# Looping a Solver Macro

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I'm trying to run through a long list of rows to optimise for a "lowest cost" solution in column J of my model.
There are four variables in columns C, D, E and F which run from Row 9 down to Row 50 and a few constraints.

Fairly new to VBA generally but the initial single line solver code is this below and essentially need to continue repeating the process to then solve for J10 by changing the variables C10 - F10, then moving onto row 11 etc.

Any pointers to start on the loop process would be much appreciated!

Cheers!

```
Sub Macro11()
SolverOk SetCell:="$J$9", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$C$9:$F$9", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$C$9", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="23"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$9", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="23"
SolverOk SetCell:="$J$9", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$C$9:$F$9", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverOk SetCell:="$J$9", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$C$9:$F$9", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve
SolverOk SetCell:="$J$9", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$C$9:$F$9", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The inputs are defined by strings representing ranges, so create the range strings by concatenating with a looping variable:

```
Sub Macro11()
    Dim iRow As Integer

    For iRow = 9 To 50
        SolverOk SetCell:="$J" & iRow, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$C" & iRow & ":$F" & iRow, _
            Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$C" & iRow, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="23"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$D" & iRow, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="23"
        SolverOk SetCell:="$J" & iRow, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$C" & iRow & ":$F" & iRow, _
            Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
        SolverOk SetCell:="$J" & iRow, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$C" & iRow & ":$F" & iRow, _
            Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
        SolverSolve
        SolverOk SetCell:="$J" & iRow, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$C" & iRow & ":$F" & iRow, _
                Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    Next iRow
End Sub
```